# How are multiple power rails controlled in sequence for a multi-voltage PCB?

Tags: voltage-regulator, fpga, switch-mode-power-supply

Lets take an example of an FPGA that has these voltage rails:

```
Power Rail  Description
VCCINT      Voltage supply for the internal core logic: supplies power to the internal logic functions, such as CLBs, block RAM, and DSP blocks.
VCCAUX      Voltage supply for auxiliary logic: supplies power to the various auxiliary circuits, such as clock managers and dedicated configuration pins.
VCCO        Voltage supply for I/O banks: powers the output buffer drivers.
MGTAVCC     Voltage supply for the GTX transceiver: powers the internal analog circuits of the GTX transceiver. This includes analog circuits for the PLLs, transmitters, and receivers.
MGTAVTT     Voltage supply for GTX transceiver termination circuits
```

These need to be ramped up in specific sequence. The sequence could be simultaneous tracking, sequential turn-on or ratiometric tracking. There is also the need to implement Soft-Start, monotonic and pre-biased startup.

If the user is using multiple linear voltage regulators, or even multiple SMPS voltage regulators, how will the correct sequence be typically implemented?

Comment: Really it all comes down to establishing the requirements of the devices you are using, from their documentation, and finding the best (for your constraints, e.g. cheapest) way of satisfying them.

Comment: Is cost the only constraint here then?

Comment: You tell me, as I said they are your constraints. I used cost as an example, but size, power consumption, heat, reliability, simplicity of diagnostics, flexbility, programmability or ease of verification could be some others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many power supply parts have "power good" outputs, and programmable soft-starts.  It can be as simple as the power good output from the first rail connecting to the enable of the second rail, and so on.  It can also be as complex as a programmable sequencing chip that monitors and sequences the rails according to requirements.  TI has some parts you can see [here](https://www.ti.com/power-management/sequencers/products.html) with an example system diagram shown below:

[image]

Other schemes using supervisor parts possibly in combination with some logic are also possible.  The final implementation depends on the specific system requiremnents.

Comment: The part of simultaneous tracking, sequential turn-on or ratiometric tracking that depends on the IC is actually quite intimidating. This means that if we have different ICs that require the same voltage value for some power rail but the sequence is different, we shall have to have different regulators to generate it.

Comment: That seems like it would only come up if two ICs require multiple rails in common, AND those in different orders. I imagine that would be unusual.

Comment: @quantum231 You wouldn't necessarily need multiple regulators with the same voltage.  You could use a load switch or switches on the same regulator if you had different sequencing requirements for the same voltage.

Comment: What is load switch? Since the different rails of same voltage of different ICs require different sequence of ramping them up, I do not see how we can get away with using the same voltage regulator for all the ICs.

Comment: @quantum231 See the following: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/use-load-switches-for-power-sequencing#:~:text=Power%20sequencing%20configuration%20options&text=Load%20switches%20control%20each%20power,oscillators%2C%20clocks%20or%20a%20processor.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement discrete timing using sequencers as shown in [John D's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/662469/103420).

There are some complex PMICs provide such functionality as well. These chips can be found in many of today's smart devices (tablets, PDAs, smartphones, etc). [This one](https://rockchip.fr/RK818%20datasheet%20V1.0.pdf), for example, has multiple buck and LDO regulators and provides programmable (not fully but to some extent) power sequencing <sup>this is not an advertisement</sup>.

Comment: Also note that it's common for a PMIC to be designed for power sequencing a specific IC or series of ICs (particularly modern CPUs).

Comment: I did not know about  power-management integrated circuits until now, they appear to be quite large (number of connections) and complex.

Answer (score 3):

FPGA boards often have power trees, in which one voltage rail is derived from another.  For example 12V -> 3.3V -> 0.9V.  There can be multiple branches, eg 5V is also derived from 12V and 1.2V is derived from 3.3V, and sometimes multiple converters (eg several 1.2V rails derived from different points).

If the converters are arranged in a tree that matches the desired voltage sequencing, the outputs will come up in the same pattern.  As mentioned by John D's answer, these converters may have enable inputs and power good outputs.  A simple way to achieve the correct timing is an R-C circuit between one power good to the next enable, which will add an appropriate delay.  I wouldn't be surprised if there is some tuning of these values during production prototyping.

Answer (score 1):

Some designs use a CPLD connected to the *Power Good* outputs and *Enable* inputs of voltage regulators to sequence the power-up for the FPGA.

E.g. for the TEF1001 from Trenz Electronic the documentation has [Power-On Sequence](https://wiki.trenz-electronic.de/display/PD/TEF1001+TRM#TEF1001TRM-Power-OnSequence) and [Power](https://wiki.trenz-electronic.de/display/PD/TEF1001+CPLD#TEF1001CPLD-Power) which shows how the on-board CPLD sequences the power-up.

Where using a CPLD gives some flexibility to tune the sequence by re-programming.

Also, some of the DC-DC converters used on the design are the [LTM4676A](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltm4676a.html) which have the I2C-based PMBus/SMBus 2-wire serial communication interface which can be used for monitoring, and are connected to the FPGA on the board. I.e. once the FPGA has booted it has the ability to perform voltage/current monitoring of some of the DC-DC converters if required.

Answer (score 1):

The specific power rails you mentioned in the question seem specific to Xilinx FPGAs. Xilinx provides free schematics of their evaluation kits so you can see exactly how they implemented the power sequencing requirements for their board designs and use that as reference for your own design.

This is pretty standard practice not just for Xilinx, but for many IC manufacturers. In some cases you may need to get an NDA, but most manufacturers benefit from providing this type of support to their customers because it increases their marketability.

Comment: There is the Xilinx application note [Simplified Power Sequencing](https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/application_notes/xapp1375-power-sequencing.pdf) which describes some different options. Albeit that application note is only for Versal ACAPs so not sure how applicable to other XIlinx device families.

Comment: Yes, it is taken from Xilinx part. However, I had to use an example so I chose Xilinx since I am familiar with their FPGAs.